# Allowing parameters with DOT in .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this on my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ ?link=$1 [L]
```

My link is example.com/?link=sometext
I want to acces that by example.com/sometext and this^ rewrite does that

Now my links has changed, they are now in this format-> 'some.text' . With a dot. The current htaccess gives me 404

How can I make this work ? I tried generators but they only gave me 500 errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `.` from your character class and have your rule as this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?link=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?link=$1 [L,QSA] . This gives me 500 error when accessing example.com/asd.asd . I can't even access example.com as it is

Comment: now it works. thank you sir.. just a quick question . I tried RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)-([^/\.]+)/?$ ?link=$1.$2 [L] . it worked for /asd-asd . but when i did ([^/\.]+).([^/\.]+) it gave me 500 ... do u have any idea why ?

Comment: What URL are you trying to rewrite using this `RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)-([^/\.]+)/?$ ?link=$1.$2 [L]` rule?

Comment: i was just trying to solve my problem.. i was accessing example.com/some-text .. and then i tried with DOT

Comment: ok `([^/\.]+).([^/\.]+)` should be written as `([^/.]+)\.([^/]+)`

Comment: Also if it worked out then pls mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.